# In some Android versions, permission requests don't appear in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

When I try to request location or any other permission with Xamarin.Android, permission request works smoothly in older Android versions, but permission request window doesn't open at all in newer versions. I have searched the internet for the cause of the problem and even sent all of the project codes to chat-gpt to ask for help on the issue, but I couldn't get permission request to work no matter how hard I tried. For instance, when I compile the project on a phone with Android version: 10 QP1A - MIUI version: MIUI Global 12.0.8, permission requests don't appear. I have shared the codes related to permission in AndroidManifest.xml and in the code below, and I need help on what might be causing the problem. Thank you in advance.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="game.cassinova" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/logo">
        <service android:name=".LocationService" android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
 protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
.
.
.
 //The first method I tried to obtain permissions is:
            string[] locationPermissions = new string[] {
                Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation,
                Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
                Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation
            };

            bool shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) ||
                                                 ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) ||
                                                 ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation);
            CoordinatorLayout constraintLayout = FindViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout);
         

            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale)
            {
                Snackbar.Make(constraintLayout, "lease grant all the permissions for the application to run smoothly.",
                    Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                    .SetAction("Okay", new Action<Android.Views.View>(delegate (Android.Views.View obj) {
                        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, locationPermissions, LocationContactsId);
                    }))
                    .Show();
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, locationPermissions, LocationContactsId);
            }


            //The second method I tried to obtain permissions is:
            if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation) == Permission.Denied || CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == Permission.Denied || CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) == Permission.Denied || CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts) == Permission.Denied || CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts) == Permission.Denied || CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState) == Permission.Denied)
            {

                RequestPermissions(locationPermissions, LocationContactsId);
            }
            else
            {
.
.
.
.




public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
//If the permissions are granted, necessary codes for location services and checks are executed in the rest of this code block... However, since the permission request window doesn't appear, the application never enters this code block in debug mode.
.
.
.
```

I have searched the internet for alternative permission request codes and asked for help from chat-gpt, but I couldn't get any results from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity 
{

    public  string TAG
    {
        get
        {
            return "MainActivity";
        }
    }

    string[] locationPermissions = new string[] {
            Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation
        };

    static readonly int LocationContactsId = 1;

    Button button;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        //if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted
        //|| ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted
        //|| ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)

        if ( ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
            Log.Info(TAG, "Location permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
            RequestLocationPermissions();
        }
        else
        {
            // Contact permissions have been granted. Show the contacts fragment.
            Log.Info(TAG, "Location permissions have already been granted. Displaying contact details.");
        }

    }

   private void RequestLocationPermissions()
    {
        bool shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) ||
                                                 ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) ||
                                                 ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation);


        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale)
        {

            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, locationPermissions, LocationContactsId);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, locationPermissions, LocationContactsId);
        }

    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
      if (requestCode == LocationContactsId)
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Received response for contact permissions request.");

            // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
            // checked.
            if (PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions(grantResults))
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "Contacts permissions is granted.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

}
```

**PermissionUtil.cs**

```
public abstract class PermissionUtil 
{

    public static bool VerifyPermissions(Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        // At least one result must be checked.
        if (grantResults.Length < 1)
            return false;

        // Verify that each required permission has been granted, otherwise return false.
        foreach (Permission result in grantResults)
        {
            if (result != Permission.Granted)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```